# div flutuante acompanhar scroll da pagina

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alguém teria alguma ideia ou exemplo SIMPLIFICADOS de como fazer uma div flutuante rolar junto com o scroll da pagina ? Algo bem simples, para entendimento e aprendizado, pois os existentes aqui são muito confusos e já estou buscando este modelo há certo tempo.
Existem aquelas div´s flutuantes que ficam no lado direito da pagina e conforme a pagina é rolada, a mesma div acompanha até o rodapé ou até determinado ponto.
Eh apenas isso. Quem puder compartilhar, agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se é exatamente isso que vc precisa, mas apenas com CSS vc pode fazer usando `position:sticky` ou `position:fixed` ou  Se vc quiser ver exemplos pela internet pode pesquisar por "css persistent div"

**Veja o exemplo com `position:sticky`:** (nesse exemplo o box começa a 120px do topo e para a 50px do topo)

```css
body {
    height: 200vh;
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/500/500);
}
.teste {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 140px; /* altura que está do topo */
    top: 50px; /* altura que vai parar antes do topo */
    position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<div class="teste"></div>
```

---

**Veja o exemplo com `position:fixed`:**

```css
body {
    height: 200vh;
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/500/500);
}
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 1rem;
    top: 1rem;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Aqui tem a documentação da Mozilla sobre o posicionamento de elementos com CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Legal, entendi, agora a pergunta é: Preciso fazer essa div percorrer "certo espaço" ...

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <p>
            conteudo fixo aqui
        </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <p>
            conteudo fixo aqui
        </p>
    </div>
          
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>conteudo da div flutuante aqui</p>
    </div>    
</div>

Tenho essa div col-md-4(lado direito) para correr entre o espaço das duas divs col-md-8 (uma em cima da outra), terei que fazer com JS o ajuste entre elas ?

Comment: Consegui @hugocsl, deu certo! segui o seu css e deu certo na hora de aplicar a classe com as divs dentro do row. Obrigado!

Comment: @EitaEhNOiz Legal jovem que bom que deu certo!

Answer (score 0):

Cara fiz um exemplo **bem** básico mesmo, acho que mais básico que isto impossível. role a barra para ver o resultado. Utilizei apenas a propriedade `display` com o valor **fixed**.

```css
div {
  height:900px;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="fixed">TESTE</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Leandro !

Comment: Por nada man!!!